# Connection refused can not use retry when use ribbon

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

info:

```
spring-cloud.version=Dalston.SR5
spring-boot-starter-parent=1.5.7.RELEASE
zuul-core=1.3.0
```

When one client's status is down(I mean kill it),but zuul can also have cache of instance info, so request will route to down client, but can't have a correct response.so zuul do retry, route request to another client and get correct response.
This condition like restart my client.

so I have some configurations:

```
ribbon:
    MaxAutoRetries: 1
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 2
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    ReadTimeout: 1000
    ConnectTimeout: 250
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 1000
zuul:
  retryable: true
```

And  I use spring-retry jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't work as I think. so I debug the code.
`RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` will be used when zuul route request. the exception throw on

```
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient#execute
final HttpResponse httpResponse = RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.this.delegate.execute(httpUriRequest);
```

I found the retry code after it, so it can't go to retry logic.
Can you give some suggests to fix this problem?
Exception info :

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.16.73.151:8701 [/172.16.73.151] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:71)
```

Comment: It should work. Could you post original exception that was caused by 'org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException'

Comment: The problem is very obvious.
This code throw a exception:
`final HttpResponse httpResponse = RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.this.delegate.execute(httpUriRequest);`

The code is in RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.

And this code can't be execute：
`this.executeWithRetry(request, retryPolicy, retryCallback);`

Comment: I guess that you misunderstood the code. `....this.delegate.execute` code exist inside `RetryCallback retryCallback` and this will be executed by `this.executeWithRetry`. And it will execute this retryCallback with RetryTemplate. That is how retry works in Spring Cloud Zuul.

Comment: You are right!The exception is happen when retry request.I found the issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2667
and  thank very much.because you said,I read codes and test many times and found this bug codes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to add follow configuration and check if it works :

```
@Configuration
public class RibbonConfig {

@Value("${ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations}")
private Boolean retryOnAllOperations;

@Value("${ribbon.MaxAutoRetries}")
private Integer maxAutoRetries;

@Value("${ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer}")
private Integer maxAutoRetriesNextServer;

@Bean
public RetryHandler retryHandler() {
    IClientConfig clientConfig = DefaultClientConfigImpl
            .Builder
            .newBuilder()
            .withMaxAutoRetries(maxAutoRetries)
            .withMaxAutoRetriesNextServer(maxAutoRetriesNextServer)
            .withRetryOnAllOperations(retryOnAllOperations)
            .build();

    RetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultLoadBalancerRetryHandler(maxAutoRetries, maxAutoRetriesNextServer, retryOnAllOperations);
    return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(true, true, retryHandler, clientConfig );
 }

@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public IRule ribbonRule() {
    return new RetryRule();
 }
}
```